# Sequelize - multiple nested models with where clause

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a model which has 2 associations, I want to return the model with both associations, but only where the criteria for one is met.

e.g.

```
        models.Users.findAll({
            include: [
                {
                    model: models.Context,
                    where: { id: req.session.contextObject.id }
                },
                {    
                    model: models.Role
                }
            ]
        }).then(function(fullUsers){...
```

So I want to return all **Users**, with their **Contexts** and **Roles**, but **only** where the **Context** matches a value I have.

Is is possible to return multiple associated models but with a where clause on one of the models?

This works absolutely fine when only including the Context model.

Comment: FYI this almost works...

   models.Users.findAll({
    include: [{all: true}],
    where: {'Contexts.id': req.session.contextObject.id}
   }).then(function(fullUsers){

...But instead of being WHERE `Users`.`Contexts.id` it needs to be WHERE `Contexts`.`id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter by the Context's ID, you could use the Context's attribute reference on Users' model:

```
models.Users.findAll({
      where : { ContextId : req.session.contextObject.id }
    , include: [
        {
            model: models.Context           
        },
        {    
            model: models.Role
        }
    ]
}).then(function(fullUsers){...
```

Comment: Ah thank you! i'll try this, I've just got it working with a RAW query instead, i.e. :     include: [{all: true}],
    where: [' `Contexts`.`id` = ' + req.session.contextObject.id]

...but I'll try this too as it feels nicer